# Can't install PostrgreSQL 9.6 - Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.6'

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, postgresql

Given

Ubuntu 22.04

I try to install PostgreSQL 9.6 (I need exact this version) like this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

But get error:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-9.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.6'
```

After use advices in comments I get error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-9.6 is already the newest version (9.6.24-3.pgdg22.04+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Comment: If `apt policy postgresql` doesn't turn up version 9.6, it is not available for your Ubuntu version and you will need to install a different PostgreSQL version.

Comment: If you need a very specific version of PostgreSQL, then your best option is to use a Docker container. This will give you the added benefit of not needing to worry about OS updates upgrading the database engine 

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the repos from Postgres as those versions are not in the Ubuntu repos.

First, import the GPG key.

```shell
curl -fsSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/postgresql.gpg
```

Next, add the repo.

```shell
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jammy-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Then you should be able to install the versions you want.

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-9.6
```